# Подсчитать количество файлов с префиксом Data_

Tags: windows, golang

Как я могу подсчитать количество файлов с префиксом `Data_`, `Complete_` в определенной директории при помощи Go?

Начинал с такой конструкции:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    counter, err := ioutil.ReadDir("C:\\Files")
    if err != nil {
        defer fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, fcount := range counter {
        fmt.Println(fcount.Name())
        var filesCount = strings.HasPrefix("Data_", fcount.Name())
        fmt.Println(filesCount)
    }
}
```

Но мне всё время выдавало `false`, хоть нужных файлов было 4 из 15, должно было быть `false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false`. Но почему то `strings.HasPrefix` не воспринимал это. А вот как поступить с подсчётом найденных файлов с префиксами`Data_`, `Complete_` я не знаю, в конце выполнения программа должна вывести на экран `Файлов с префиксом Data_: 4. Файлов с префиксом Complete_: 10`

Comment: А какие имена печатаются? Может у вас там `data_foo` или `Data foo`вместо `Data_foo`.

Comment: вам надо бы `strings.HasPrefix(fcount.Name(), "Data_")` :)

Comment: @biosckon Пишите ответ :)

Comment: @biosckon спасибо! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спецификация функции:

```golang
func HasPrefix(s, prefix string) bool
```

Вам нужо было просто поменять местами аргументы. Наверное кодили без кофе. :)

```golang
var filesCount = strings.HasPrefix(fcount.Name(), "Data_")
```